# JQuery - Evertything except button + submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery confirm ("Are you sure you want to leave before saving?") that sets "isModified" to true when a textbox or textarea have been changed. Problem now is that when I press a button (Save..) the confirm shows.

Is there a way to make it skip confirm when pressing buttons?

```
// Confirm leaving page
var isModified = false;
var modifiedMsg = 'Are you sure?';

$('textarea,input').change(function(){
    if(!isModified){
        isModified = true;
      }
  });        

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(isModified){
        return modifiedMsg;
     }
  };
```

Comment: Yes. Have the save button switch `isModified` back to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to make a dirty check.  You may want to make these changes:

Instead of trying to catch which buttons are pressed, what you really care about (i'm assuming), is when you are submitting a form?

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
   isFormSubmitting = true;
});
```

Then on your dirty check, make sure both are set accordingly.  It's dangerous to just use one flag since submitting the form can wipe out the dirty state.

```
$(window).unload(function(e) {
    if(isModified && !isFormSubmitting){
        return modifiedMsg;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually if your button is also `input type="submit"` it will qualify for being in selector. You can be specific by either using selector with attributes

`$('textarea,input[type=text]')`

or use not filter with `input[type=submit]`

Comment: Doesnt solve it. When changing stuff so isModified = true, pressing button still shows confirm box.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('textarea,input[type!="submit"],input[type!="button"]')
```

Comment: Doesnt solve it. When changing stuff so isModified = true, pressing button still shows confirm box

Comment: don't forget to reset isModified = false after showing confirm box